# jQuery not working for custom tabs in magento product view page

Tags: jquery, magento, tabs, magento-1.9

I am trying to add few custom tabs to product view page in my theme. I am able to see the content but jQuery is not coming to effect. Below are  details can someone please check and advice if anything extra need to be done.

**Edit:** I am using magento 1.9.2.2

**app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml**

```js
            <script type="text/javascript">
          
                alert("YEs!");
                $.noConflict();
                $('ul.tabs').each(function(){
                  // For each set of tabs, we want to keep track of
                  // which tab is active and its associated content
                  var $active, $content, $links = $(this).find('a');

                  // If the location.hash matches one of the links, use that as the active tab.
                  // If no match is found, use the first link as the initial active tab.
                  $active = $($links.filter('[href="'+location.hash+'"]')[0] || $links[0]);
                  $active.addClass('active');

                  $content = $($active[0].hash);

                  // Hide the remaining content
                  $links.not($active).each(function () {
                       $(this.hash).hide();
                  });

                  // Bind the click event handler
                  $(this).on('click', 'a', function(e){
                  // Make the old tab inactive.
                     $active.removeClass('active');
                     $content.hide();

                  // Update the variables with the new link and content
                     $active = $(this);
                     $content = $(this.hash);

                  // Make the tab active.
                     $active.addClass('active');
                     $content.show();

                  // Prevent the anchor's default click action
                     e.preventDefault();
                  });
                  
                });
             
           </script>
```

```html
<div class="custom-nav">
                <ul class="tabs">
                    <li><a href="#tab1">Description</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab2">Details</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#tab3">Reviews</a></li>
                </ul>           
                <div class="custom-block-details" id="tab1">
                    <?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="custom-block-details" id="tab2">
                    <h4><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></h4>                 
                </div>
                <div class="custom-block-details" id="tab3">
                    <h4>Reviews</h4>
                    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>                 
                </div>
            </div>
```

**app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/layout/page.xml**

```html
<block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>lib/ccard.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/builder.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/effects.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/dragdrop.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/controls.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>scriptaculous/slider.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/form.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>varien/menu.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>mage/cookies.js</script></action>
                <action method="addJs"><script>js/jquery-1.7.2.js</script></action>
                <!--<action method="addJs"><script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script></action>-->
                <!--<action method="addJs"><script>jsproductViewNavbar.js</script></action>-->

                <block type="page/js_cookie" name="js_cookies" template="page/js/cookie.phtml"/>

                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/styles.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/styles-ie.css</name><params/><if>lt IE 8</if></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/widgets.css</stylesheet></action>
                <action method="addCss"><stylesheet>css/print.css</stylesheet><params>media="print"</params></action>

                <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>lib/ds-sleight.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
                <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/ie6.js</name><params/><if>lt IE 7</if></action>
            </block>
```

Comment: I found only this post somewhat similar to mine.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18696172/how-include-jquery-tabs-in-product-view-phtml-in-magento-1-7-0-2

But it is all about conflicts not on how to include required files.

Comment: is there any error in your browser console?

Comment: No.Console is empty. I checked both 'Errors' and 'All' tabs. And one more thing I am using Magento 1.9.2.2, does it count any difference?

Answer (score 0):

using  jQuery instance of $
like  ** jQuery.noConflict() ** 
   and write

```
jQuery.noConflict()
```

in  the buttom of the jquery-1.7.2.js  file  instance of view.phtml
and also change the permission of your js  file (read/write)

Comment: I tried the same but no luck. Still the same result.